# Split a character list based on another list Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have to split a list of characters such that it gets cut when it encounters a vowel. For example, a string like

```
toy = ['b', 'a', 'm', 'b', 'i', 'n', 'o']
```

the output should be

```
[('b', 'a'), ('m', 'b', 'i'), ('n', 'o')]
```

I tried to run 2 loops, one behind the other.

```
# usr/bin/env/python

apple = []
consonants = ('k', 'h', 'b', 'n')
vowels = ('i', 'a', 'u')
toy = ('k', 'h', 'u', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'i')
for i in range(len(toy)):
    if i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        if toy[i] in vowels:
            for k in range(i - 1, len(toy)):
                if toy[k - 1] in consonants:
                    n = toy[i - k:i - 1]
                    apple.append(n)
                    break
print apple
```

But this does not let me come out of the loop once the vowel is reached. Using the "bambino" example, it gives me something like `[('b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'm', 'b', 'i'), ('b', 'a', 'm', 'b', 'i', 'n', 'o')]`. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be overcomplicating things. A simple solution for this would be -

```
>>> toy = ['b', 'a', 'm', 'b', 'i', 'n', 'o']
>>> vowels = ['a','i','e','o','u']
>>> apples = []
>>> k = 0
>>> for i ,x in enumerate(toy):
...     if x in vowels:
...             apples.append(tuple(toy[k:i+1]))
...             k = i+1
...
>>> apples
[('b', 'a'), ('m', 'b', 'i'), ('n', 'o')]
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function returns the index as well as the current element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have a temporary list and a result list
2. loop through the elements, till the the end is reached
3. add the current element to the temporary list
4. if the current element is a vowel, then add the temporary list to the result list and empty the temporary list
5. goto step 2

---

```
>>> result = []
>>> temp = []
>>> for char in toy:
...     temp.append(char)
...     if char.lower() in "aeiou":
...         result.append(temp)
...         temp = []
...  if temp:
...      result.append(temp)
... 
>>> result
[['b', 'a'], ['m', 'b', 'i'], ['n', 'o']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this :

```
#usr/bin/env/python

apple = []
vowels = ('i', 'a', 'u')
toy = ('k', 'h', 'u', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'i')
collector = []
for i in toy:
    collector.append(i)
    if i in vowels:
        apple.append(collector)
        collector = []

print apple
```

Result:

```
[['k', 'h', 'u'], ['b', 'a'], ['n', 'i']]
```

Comment: Thank you all. I have tried all of your solutions, and they  work like a charm. You have saved a lot of struggle. Now I have to take this result to the next step.